Due to protobuf-net RuntimeTypeModel class, the complex datatype such as Dictionary<string,string[]> are not getting converted to proto schema
The protobuf-net RuntimeTypeModel class has a function TryGetRepeatedProvider which checks if a C# data type is a proto's "repeated" type and its c# System.Reflection.MemeberInfo type is present (e.g. string[] or List or Dictionary<T,K>)  then do not create its proto schema.
Example:
c# Dictionary<string,string[]> is not getting converted to proto schema :
// below Array_String  message is not getting generated.
message Array_String { 
   repeated string item = 1;
}

// KeyValuePair_String_Array_String message is getting generated
message KeyValuePair_String_Array_String { 
   string Key = 1;
   Array_String Value = 2; // getting generated too
}

the message Array_String is not getting generated because c# string[] System.Reflection.Memberinfo type is available to RuntimeTypeModel.

When c# System.Reflection.Memberinfo type is available why its message
is not generated in proto?

If those are not generated then the above-mentioned complex types are
not working, what could be a workaround?

If we try to bypass the below mentioned check in RuntimeTypeModel
class's GetSchema function what could go wrong ?
This instruction :
TryGetRepeatedProvider(tmp.Type) is not null) continue;






Dictionary<string,string[]> or  Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>> these c# types should be parsed and their proto schema should be generated.

